# Print the derivate of a polynome - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a school-exercise to make a program that prints the derivate of a input polynome. I found a code on this site that worked almost as good as i wanted. Because of my lack of programming skills in this particular exercise i need some more help.

So, the polynomes i need to calculate is down in the "run(xxxxxxxx)" line in the bottom, and it almost works. The first should print "4x^3 + 12x^2 + 1", but prints "4x^3+9x^2+". The second one i need to find out how to add the possibility to calculate with a "y" also in the polynome.

I guess the problem might be that the program can't calculate all the lines, and that's why it's 9x^2 instead of 12x^2.

Can anyone give me a tip how to go forward or show me the code so i can learn how to make it?

```
import re

def read(eq):
    terms = eq.split('+')
    equation = [re.split('x\^?', t) for t in terms]
    eq_map = []
    for e in equation:
        try:
            coeff = int(e[0])
        except ValueError:
            coeff = 1
        try:
            power = int(e[1])
        except ValueError:
            power = 1
        except IndexError:
            power = 0
        eq_map.append((coeff, power))
    return eq_map

def write(eq_map):
    def str_power(p):
        if p == 0:
            return ''
        elif p == 1:
            return 'x'
        else:
            return 'x^%d' % (p,)

    def str_coeff(c):
        return '' if c == 1 else str(c)
    str_terms = [(str_coeff(c) + str_power(p)) for c, p in eq_map]
    return "+".join(str_terms)

def derivative(eq):
    eq_map = read(eq)
    der_map = [(p*c, p-1) for c, p in eq_map[:-1]]
    return write(der_map)

def run(eq):
    print (eq, '->', derivative(eq))

run("x^4 + 3x^3 + x +x^3")
run("x^3 + xy")
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I think your code contains some issues (looks some sort of indentation issue near `def str_coeff(c):` that you may want to fix). Also, if you want to work with mathematical expressions in Python you may be interested in [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @norok2. Will check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code is not able to process the second equation, because it assumes terms following this pattern: `ax^b`, `a^x`, `x^b` or `a`, while you give it an unexpected `xy`. I could not guess what is the expected output here. If you want to allow it to live after (or before) the x part, you have to specify how and implement it.

For the first equation, there are different problems.

One logical problem is that you failed to normalize the polygone, that is to factorize terms with same exponent value. Easy to do if no `y` involved, but if you want to process them, you will have to explicitely accept and process polynoms having 2 variables.

Then `read` function looks correct, provided no `y` is involved, but I would do the normalization here:

```
def read(eq):
    terms = eq.split('+')
    equation = [re.split('x\^?', t) for t in terms]
    eq_map = []
    for e in equation:
        try:
            coeff = int(e[0])
        except ValueError:
            coeff = 1
        try:
            power = int(e[1])
        except ValueError:
            power = 1
        except IndexError:
            power = 0
        eq_map.append((coeff, power))
    # Normalize the polynom
    old = [0, -1]
    new_map = []
    for e in sorted(eq_map, key = lambda x: x[1],reverse=True):
        if e[1] == old[1]:
                old[0] += e[0]
        else:
                old = list(e)
                new_map.append(old)
    return [tuple(i) for i in new_map]
```

Then `str_coeff` is wrong because `1` should not become `''` but stay 1:

```
def write(eq_map):
    def str_power(p):
        if p == 0:
            return ''
        elif p == 1:
            return 'x'
        else:
            return 'x^%d' % (p,)

    def str_coeff(c, p):
        return '' if (c == 1 and p != 0) else str(c)
    str_terms = [(str_coeff(c, p) + str_power(p)) for c, p in eq_map]
    return "+".join(str_terms)
```

And in `derivative` you must not inconditionaly drop the last term, but drop the term of power 0 **if any**:

```
def derivative(eq):
    eq_map = read(eq)
    der_map = [(p*c, p-1) for c, p in eq_map if p != 0]
    return write(der_map)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer! Works like a charm for the first task. I've tried to look where i can put the code to make the 2:nd (the y) polynome, but can't get it to work. Do you have any idea how to make that work? Thanks alot! :)

Comment: I found something else. How can i make it work if i input (-) in the polynome. As of now, it splits as all (+). Thanks :)